# How to get the text from the inner span tag

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Below is the html tag. I want to return the value in span as an integer in python selenium.

Can you help me out?

```html
<span class="pendingCount">
 <img src="/static/media/sandPot.a436d753.svg" alt="sandPot">
 <span>2</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all the element of type `span`, find their value:

```
elements = driver.findElementsByCSS("span[]")
// loop over the elements find the text inside them
element.getAttribute("text")
// or
element.getAttrtibute("value")
// if the text or value are not empty - you have the number
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the text ***2*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.pendingCount img[alt='sandPot'][src*='sandPot'] +span").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pendingCount']//img[@alt='sandPot' and contains(@src, 'sandPot')]//following::span[1]").text)
  ```

---

To extract the text ***2*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.pendingCount img[alt='sandPot'][src*='sandPot'] +span"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pendingCount']//img[@alt='sandPot' and contains(@src, 'sandPot')]//following::span[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)